# How do I open an HttpClient connection in Android and then close it immediately

Tags: java, android, sockets, httpclient

I am digging for quite a while and I am wondering how do I open an HttpClient connection in Java (Android) and then close the socket(s) right away without getting CLOSE_WAIT and TIME_WAIT TCP statuses while I am checking network monitoring tools.

What I am doing is (Found this solution on stackoverflow site):

```
String url = "http://example.com/myfile.php";

String result = null;

InputStream is = null;

StringBuilder sb = null;

    try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

After I run this code - The PHP file is executed well, I get the response back to TOAST, BUT - when I analyze the networking environment of my mobile device with external network analyzer tool - I see that the connection(s) stay in CLOSE_WAIT or/and TIME_WAIT for about 1 minute and only then they move to CLOSED state.

The problem is:
I am calling the above function every ~2 to 5 seconds in an infinite loop, which result over time a huge amount of CLOSE_WAITs and TIME_WAITs - which affect the overall performance of my Android app, until it gets stuck and useless !

What I want to do is (And need your answer if possible):
I wish to really close the connection RIGHT AWAY after I TOAST the response message without any open sockets. No TIME_WAIT and no CLOSE_WAIT. No left overs at all - close all communication IMMEDIATELY at the split second that I run code that should do so. I don't need the connection anymore until the next iteration of the loop.

How can I accomplish that ?
I have in mind that I don't want the application to halt or have poor performance over time, since it should run in a service/stay open forever.

I would really appreciate if you could write simple code that work after I do copy-paste.
I am new to Java and Android, so I will try to figure out the code that you write, so please keep it as simple as possible. Thanks a lot !

Question asker.

Comment: Did you try: httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

Comment: Hi Philipp, Yes I did. I tried .shutdown and I tried .close() - all leave traces of CLOSE_WAIT/TIME_WAIT for about a minute or more. Since I need to run this code in a loop every few seconds - I have problems as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using HttpURLConnection class. refer to following link :
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

in the finally clause just call disconnect. Example code ..

```
try {
    HttpURLConnection locConn = (HttpURLConnection) locurl.openConnection();
                    //URL url = locConn.getURL();
    locConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    locConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    locConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    locConn.setRequestProperty("X-Myauthtoken", userCredentials);
    retc = locConn.getResponseCode();
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(locConn.getInputStream()));

    String sessionK = null;
    readVal = reader.readLine();

    if (retc == 200) {


    }

}catch (...)
{
    //handle exception 
}finally {
    //disconnect here
    locConn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: This code piece looks interesting ! It keeps only one connection open in CLOSE_WAIT. Once I run it again in my loop - It closes the previous connection. reopens it and immediately moves it to a new CLOSE_WAIT with a new timestamp. The most important thing is that the previous CLOSE_WAIT turned to CLOSE, so no duplicate CLOSE_WAITs exist to overload the app. The thing is however, that I don't see when the single CLOSE_WAIT turns to CLOSE eventually. It stays open all the time. Is there a way to kill the last CLOSE_WAIT too ? Thanks !

Comment: If you read about disconnect method on Android developers website I think it will solve your problem ...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html.  this link

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("http://www.myhost.com/");
try {
    httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpget.getResponseBodyAsStream(),                    httpget.getResponseCharSet()); 
    // consume the response entity
  } finally {
    httpget.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sweet Guy, Unfortunately I cannot even compile the code that you provided. Eclipse does not recognize it to be imported as suggest other methods. I am trying to read about the httpclient in Android Developers forum and it says that "This interface was deprecated in API level 22." for the httpclient. Do you have any alternative ?